# How to destroy insect hives without taking damage?

Tags: resident-evil-7

There are swarms of smaller, around life-sized insects around hives. In order to destroy the hives close contact is mandatory and the swarm always attacks me, often more than once. Spraying the insects with fire seems to have no effect.

[image]

Comment: Flame grounds for the grenade launcher could be a solution, but I doubt you can get an access to the weapon before this area.

Comment: Fire works just fine, if it isn't working then you are not aiming very well or for long enough (though it doesn't take long). Surprisingly the shotgun seems to take care of them too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insect swarms are vulnerable to fire, but will not die immediately. You need to use flamethrower around 2-3 seconds to kill a single swarm (even on easy). Kill all swarms close to hive, and start burn hive. While you are constantly burning hive, new insects will not go out.

Comment: Rather than burning for a specific duration, look out (and listen) for the 'pops'. They will gush and make a popping sound 3 times, the 3rd of which will indicate the hive is destroyed. So stop flaming when you see/hear the 3rd.